# Change column's properties values

Tags: vb6

How do I change all the column values (Nullable=True and Allow Zero Length=True) in a table except PersonalID column? When the script is executed I get the error
 "-2147217887 - Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."
This is the code only for one table.I need to create more tables so setting Nullable property of each column is not practical.Please Help!

```
Public Sub DBcreation()
Dim tbl As New Table
Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog
Dim col As ADOX.Column
Dim prp As ADOX.Property
Dim oCn As ADODB.Connection
Dim sConStr As String


'Set Connection string
 sConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & App.Path & "\mydbase.mdb" & ";" & _
                        "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=4;"
' 1) Create the DataBase
 cat.Create sConStr

' 2) Create Table name "PDetails"
 tbl.Name = "PDetails"
' 3) Add  Fields
 With tbl.Columns
 .Append "PersonalID", adInteger  'Number
 .Append "GHName", adVarWChar, 50 'Text
 .Append "FirstName", adVarWChar, 50 'Text
 .Append "FHName", adVarWChar, 50 'Text
 .Append "Surname", adVarWChar, 50 'Text
 .Append "BirthDate", adDate
 .Append "Gender", adVarWChar, 10 'Text
 .Append "Address", adLongVarWChar 'Memo
 .Append "Pincode", adInteger  'Number
 .Append "MobileNo", adInteger 'Number
 .Append "HomeNo", adInteger 'Number
 .Append "MaritalStatus", adVarWChar, 10 'Text
 .Append "Profession", adVarWChar, 50 'Text
 .Append "BloodGroup", adVarWChar, 10 'Text
 .Append "Photo", adVarWChar, 50 'Text

 ' 4) 'Set the field properties.


 With !PersonaltID 'AutoNumber.
 .ParentCatalog = cat
 .Properties("Autoincrement") = True
 .Properties("Description") = "Automatically " & _
 "generated unique identifier for this record."
 End With

 With !BirthDate
 Set .ParentCatalog = cat
 .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Column Validation Rule") = _
  "Is Null Or <=Date()"
 .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Column Validation Text") = _
  "Birth date cannot be future."
 End With

 End With
 ' 5) Save the Table to the DataBase
    cat.Tables.Append tbl
' 6) Set Column Properties    
   For Each col In tbl.Columns
   For Each prp In col.Properties
   If col.Name <> "PersonalID" Then
    If prp.Name = "Nullable" Then
    prp.Value = True 'error generated
    '-2147217887 - Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.
    End If
    End If
  Next
  Next

 'Clean up

  Set tbl = Nothing
  Set cat = Nothing
  set prp = Nothing
  End Sub
```

Comment: Just a tiny typo  'With !PersonaltID 'AutoNumber.' should be 'With !PersonalID 'AutoNumber.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want both the Allow Zero Length and Nullable properties to be set to true. It would appear that MS Access doesn't allow you to set the Nullable property via ADOX, just as it isn't possible, as far as I know, to set the Allow Zero Length property with an ADO command, so you need to use both ADOX and an ADO command. Here is how I would go about doing it :

```
 6) Set Column Properties
    For Each col In tbl.Columns
        For Each prp In col.Properties
            If col.Name <> "PersonalID" Then
                col.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Allow Zero Length").Value = True
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Set oCn = cat.ActiveConnection

    SetColumnToNullable oCn, "PDetails", "GHName", "VARCHAR(50)"

    oCn.Close

    '''
  End Sub


Private Sub SetColumnToNullable(ByRef poCn As ADODB.Connection, _
                                ByVal pstrTableName As String, _
                                ByVal pstrColumnName As String, _
                                ByVal pstrDataType As String)

    poCn.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & pstrTableName & " ALTER COLUMN " & pstrColumnName & " " & pstrDataType & " NULL"
End Sub
```

An additional benefit of this method is that previously the Catalog opened a connection to the database that was kept open after the execution has completed.

With the

```
oCn.Close
```

that is no longer a problem.